# why i cant return rows between two dates with timestamp correctly

Tags: mysql

how to return exactly rows between two dates with timestamps

this code didn't return all row between 01-04 and 07-05

so what is the problem and why it didn't work correctly

and how to select rows between two date with timestamp when i use date

format like this 01-04-2015

```
SELECT d_send_items.si_id ,
  DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(d_send_items.si_send_date), '%d-%m-%Y')
FROM d_send_items WHERE
  DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(d_send_items.si_send_date), '%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN '01-04-2015' AND '07-05-2015'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`date_format` returns a *string,* so `between` is using *string* comparisons to figure out whether the values are between those two you provide.

So, unless your date format is something like `yyyy-mm-dd`, `between` is *not* going to work as you expect.

For example, the *date* `08-04-2015` is between the two dates `01-04-2015` and `07-05-2015` but the *string* `08-04-2015` is not between the two strings `01-04-2015` and `07-05-2015`, because the most significant portion `08` is beyond the range which terminates at `07...`.

So you *could* use:

```
where
  date_format(from_unixtime(d_send_items.si_send_date), '%Y-%m-%d')
   between '2015-04-01' and '2015-05-07'
```

but per-row functions never scale well in relational databases.

If they're proper `timestamp` fields, I think you can also bypass the conversion and use something like:

```
where d_send_items.si_send_date >= '01-04-2015'
  and d_send_items.si_send_date <  '08-05-2015'
```

(noting the `< day following` bit for the second conditional since `08-05-2015` is the same as `08-05-2015 00:00:00`) assuming MySQL will recognise those date formats as `dd-mm-yyyy`.

However, even if it doesn't and you have to use some function to turn those string into `timestamp` values, this is something that would be done *once* for the whole query rather than (most likely) for every single row.